# node Cannot POST /api/register

Tags: node.js

I'm not sure why I am getting the cannot POST error. I am passing the correct routes. The server is listening on a port.

index.js

```
const router = require('./router');
var app = express()
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function() {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port", port);
  });

router(app);
```

router.js

```
const Authentication = require('./authentication');
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');

const requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });
const requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false });

module.exports = function(app) {

  const apiRoutes = express.Router();
  const authRoutes = express.Router();

  apiRoutes.use('/auth', authRoutes);
  authRoutes.post('/login', requireLogin, Authentication.login);
  authRoutes.post('/register', Authentication.register);
  app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access `/api/register`, but look at the way you've registered your routers:

```
apiRoutes.use('/auth', authRoutes);
authRoutes.post('/login', requireLogin, Authentication.login);
authRoutes.post('/register', Authentication.register);
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

You've made `authRoutes` a child of `apiRoutes`, so `/register` is being served at `api/auth/register`.

Easy mistake to make when you've got several routers all linked up to each other :)